# Django: Querying  time from  datetime fields

Tags: django, django-models

On o postgresql db based Django, how can I filter by time for a datetimefield as below?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

IE: I want to filter Foo objects with "16:30" start_date and "19:00" end_date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about adding in a TimeField?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield

Otherwise you would need to write a custom query to take advantage of the database´s time capabilites since DateTimeFields don't have that capability natively in Django.

You could consider writing a function to denormalize hours and minutes from start_date to a new start_time field and then query the start_time field.

Comment: Who downvoted this? Maybe add a comment to say what is worng with this solution when you downvote it? I'm always surprised to see how many people don't want to denormalize their databases. This fear of denormalization for me actually adds application complexity and slows down applications as they grow larger. See http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html#Denormalize

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my own q:

```
   def query_by_times(start_hour, start_min, end_hour, end_min):
        query = 'EXTRACT(hour from start_date) = %i and EXTRACT(minute from start_date) = %i and EXTRACT(hour from end_date) = %i and EXTRACT(minute from end_date) = %i' % (start_hour, start_min, end_hour, end_min)
        return Foo.objects.extra(where=[query])
```

Comment: Keep in mind that any query that is doing a function call like this will slow down as the number of records increases. At some point, if you notice a slow down, denormalization should offer speed advantages on reads.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, database normalization looks like thebest solution, since execution time and system load will rise as your related database table keeps more records...

Another solution to do this **without using database filer functions** is using *filter alongside lambda*:

```
from datetime import time
records = Foo.objects.all()
filtered = filter(lambda x: (time(16,30)==x.start_date.time() and time(19,0)==x.end_date.time()), records)
```

But using this on a large dataset will need too much time and system resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Foo.objects.filter(start_date = MyDate1, end_date = MyDate2)
```

where `MyDate1` and `MyDate2` are your defined datetime objects. It should work, right?

Comment: alas "16:30" is a Time objects, otherwise I have no problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think which you need uses the range[1].

[1]http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#range