# Is there a way to query on the TIME component of datetime field in queryset?

Tags: django

There is the TIME() function in MySQL, and the year/month/date/weekday in Django queryset filter. But why is there no time (or hour/minute/second)?  Is there a workaround where i can query by time without resorting to custom sql or iterating over the actual objects (too many, too slow)?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeField` model fields don't natively support this.  You'd need to either use custom SQL or break the time out into its own `TimeField`.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5273265) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.objects.extra(where=["TIME(datetimefield) = '12:12:12'"])
```